# 400 Bad Request on XML POST

Tags: xml, perl, http-post, cisco, http-status-code-400

I'm sending a Post request to CISCO ISE with XML data and I receive the following error:

```
 400 Bad Request
```

I have checked my XML text, headers and authentication data in the RestClient (for RESTful web Services), it successfully makes the Post request. However, my request is failing with it's intended client and I believe there is something wrong with my script.

The API Documentation states that I should have the following:

```
Method: POST
 URI: https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice
 HTTP 'Content-Type' header:application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml; charset=utf-8    
 HTTP 'Accept' header: application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml
```

Can smb tell me that is wrong with my XML data? Or what does this errow say?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON -support_by_pp;
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use REST::Client;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request;
use XML::Simple;

#Create a user agent object
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts=> {
   SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
   verify_hostname => 0,
   }
   );


 my $uri='https://10.10.10.10:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/';
 my $header = HTTP::Headers->new;
 my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $uri);

 my $message =('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <ns3:networkdevice name="LAB-WLZZ" id="89c7e480-591f-11e4-ac6a b83861d71000" xmlns:ns2="ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:ns3="network.ers.ise.cisco.com">
     <authenticationSettings>
         <enableKeyWrap>false</enableKeyWrap>
         <keyInputFormat>ASCII</keyInputFormat>
         <networkProtocol>RADIUS</networkProtocol>
         <radiusSharedSecret>******</radiusSharedSecret>
     </authenticationSettings>
      <NetworkDeviceIPList>
         <NetworkDeviceIP>
             <ipaddress>9.9.9.9</ipaddress>
             <mask>21</mask>
         </NetworkDeviceIP>
      </NetworkDeviceIPList>
      <NetworkDeviceGroupList>
         <NetworkDeviceGroup>Location</NetworkDeviceGroup>
         <NetworkDeviceGroup>DeviceType</NetworkDeviceGroup>
      </NetworkDeviceGroupList>
  </ns3:networkdevice>')
   ;

    $req->header('Accept'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');
    $req->header('Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml');


    $req->content($message);
    $req->content_type("charset=utf-8");
    $req-> authorization_basic("user", "user");

 #Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
    my $res = $ua->request($req);

 #Check the outcome of the response
   if ($res->is_success) {
      print $res->status_line, "n";
          } else {
              print $res->status_line, "n";
          }
```

Comment: You're not actually using REST::Client, even though you `use REST::Client;`. Why aren't you doing `my $client = REST::Client->new(...)`?

Comment: What do Server Message Blocks (SMB) have to do with this?

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the Content-Type header to `charset=utf-8` with

```
$req->content_type("charset=utf-8");
```

This *replaces* the header's previous value of

```
application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml
```

with

```
charset=utf-8
```

You should do

```
$req->content_type(
    'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml; charset=utf-8'
);
```

---

You can also build your request like this:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $uri, [
    Accept         => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.0+xml; charset=utf-8'
], $message);
```

Comment: Tip: `Content_Type` can also be used instead of `'Content-Type'` if you want to avoid the quotes.

Comment: I wouldn't specify a charset at all. While it's needed for text formats, it's not for XML and other "application" formats.

Comment: Thank you for advices...but It doens't work, I have still error `400 Bad Request` .  Is my text XML issued correct? I mean how I should pack that `('` or just `'`, but actually I tried already everything...

Comment: @StayCalm Parentheses make zero difference in that context. Try printing `$res->decoded_content`...maybe the API returns a more detailed error message in the response body.